# Prove that any number of the form $a_3a_2a_1a_3a_2a_1$ is divisible by 91.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Prove that any number of the form $a_3a_2a_1a_3a_2a_1$ is divisible by 91.

I got up to $a_3a_2a_1a_3a_2a_1$ = 1000001$a_3$ + 10010$a_2$ + 1100$a_1$. 
However none of the coefficients are divisible by 91=13*7 ....

Comment: Look again.  Your answer is for a palindrome. $a_3a_2a_1a_1a_2a_3$

Answer (score 2):

Not quite: You mean to have

$$100100a_1 + 10010 a_2 + 1001 a_3 = 1001 (\text{stuff})$$

Answer (score 1):

We can actually factor a (four-digit) multiple of 91 out of this. Not sure how much more I can say without giving the answer away.

EDIT: You can in fact factor out 1001: $$a_3a_2a_1a_3a_2a_1=1001\cdot a_3a_2a_1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $1001 = 91 \cdot 11$, so it would be enough if you showed the number to be divisible by $1001$. Multiplying a three-digit number by $1001$ gives...